# content type with a variable amount of elements

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have posted this question to the plone user mailing list as well, so I hope nobody minds that, especially since it is nothing I have hidden.

Since my question is hard to put into a generic question, I'll try to explain it with a (hopefully) illustrative example. Please bear with me on this one.

- Content Type: Product

  Each product shall have several explanatory sections with a title and a rich text as the  section contents. Said title should be either taken from a listen of predefined titles (by the editor) or entered freely once (the exception).

Since the site will use Dexterity and requires a multilingual approach (plone.app.multilingual), centralizing the titles saves the translators some headaches and avoids unnecessary duplicates. Also in general, the styling is done through Diazo, so the sections will be mapped on a nice widget.

My problem is, how to map this onto Plone with usability for the editors and translators as well as efficiency for the software stack in mind.

- Approach 1

  Put the titles in a hidden folder and use a vocabulary in the Product content type. Also make the Product a folderish content type and require the editors to enter each section as a separate item into said folder (e.g. ProductSection non-folderish content type). Repeating that process for each product. But this seems not very user friendly and imho would not scale very well with the number of products and sections.
- Approach 2

  I could naturally also reduce the Product content type in general to just one single rich text field and have the user enter each section as a div block with a headline and a paragraph. Even though this is the easier way to implement this, it puts the burden on the translators (many duplicate translations) and on the editors (e.g. changing a title for marketing or whatever, requires changing it manually through all products etc.).

Again, please remember this is an illustrative example of my problem and here Product is really that, a product from a company's portfolio and not a Plone add-on. ;)

So my question basically boils down to this: Which approach sounds more reasonable? Or is there a more standard and/or creative way to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions and help in advance. It is very much appreciated...

### UPDATE

After I received a very enlightening answer on the plone users list, my current thinking (untested, brainstorming) is as follows:

- Product will be a custom form (due to MultiWidget, see below)
- the section blocks will be saved in a list on the Product object (titles will be a choice field only)
- the section titles will be saved elsewhere and manageable through different means (needs to be accessible by a Site Administrator, so anything ZMI is out of the question)
- easy editing through z3c.form's MultiWidget (that's the key ingredient, actually)

If this works out and plays nicely with Dexterity and multilingual, I guess that's quite the optimal solution for everyone involved.
Naturally I'd appreciate any and all kinds of comments or suggestions. Maybe I am totally on the wrong track now but based on what I read up, this should actually work fine.